# How to use a custom domain with a Azure Container App?

Tags: azure, azure-container-apps

I created two Azure Container App inside an Container App Environment;
Then they got URLs similar to this:

`backend.agreeablehill-XYZABC.canadacentral.azurecontainerapps.io`

`my-container-app.agreeablehill-XYZABC.canadacentral.azurecontainerapps.io`

Both of which have a static IP Address like this [2*.1**.2**.1**]
If I access the Web Browser on these URL the Apps respond the expected content and `HTTP 200 OK`

Then I accessed CloudFlare Panel for my domain and created two CNAME records on the DNS:

```
Type: CNAME
Name: backend
Content: backend.agreeablehill-XYZABC.canadacentral.azurecontainerapps.io

Type: CNAME
Name: app
Content: my-container-app.agreeablehill-XYZABC.canadacentral.azurecontainerapps.io
```

Now if I `PING` `backend.mydomainxyz.com` or `app.mydomainxyz.com` the DNS correctly resolves the domain to the static IP address. But If I open the URL in the Web Browser, then it gives an `HTTP 404 ERROR`

How to use a custom domain with a Azure Container App?

Update:
"Not yet. Coming in next few weeks. For now you’d have to wrap with like API M or Azure front door to provide till then", [Jeff Hollan](https://twitter.com/jeffhollan/status/1481457935402233864).

Comment: looking for the same. Looks like its currently not supported

Comment: Alternatively to API Management or Azure Front Door I would suggest Application Gateway.

Answer (score 0):

It is now possible to configure custom domain as per documentation:

- [Custom domain names and certificates in Azure Container Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-apps/custom-domains-certificates)

Interesting points:

> Azure Container Apps allows you to bind one or more custom domains to a container app.
>
> - Every domain name must be associated with a domain certificate.
> - Certificates are applied to the container app environment and are bound to individual container apps. You must have role-based access to the environment to add certificates.
> - [SNI domain certificates](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication) are required.
>   Ingress must be enabled for the container app